# How can I make my submit button take the user to a second page without interfering with my Python code?

Tags: html, flask, twilio

I'm currently working on a form with Flask. The user inputs their name and feedback into two boxes, and I use an API to send the strings to my phone number. Currently, I am trying to make it so that after the text is submitted, they are taken to a different page. I have tried a couple of things such as changing the "action" of my form and returning the render template of my second page. However, these have resulted in me being immediately sent a blank SMS message and the second page showing a 404, and the site taking the user to the second page immediately and sending a blank SMS (respectively). Sorry if my explanation here was a bit unclear.

Summary- I am trying to make the user be taken to a second page upon form submission, but I am facing some issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML-

```html
<form method="POST" class="formone" >
    <input style="font-size:55px !important; font-family: 'Ubuntu', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: center; margin: 10px;" type='text' name='name' placeholder='Your name' /><br/>
    <input style="font-size:55px !important; font-family: 'Ubuntu', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: center; margin: 10px;" type='text' name='message' placeholder='Your message'/><br/>
    <input type='submit' id="feedbackbutton" value='submit' />
</form>
```

Python-

```py
@app.route("/contact.html", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def contact():
    sender = request.form.get('name')
    message = request.form.get('message')
    client.messages.create(to="+12672747668",
                           from_="+15104661095",
                           body=f"From [{sender}]: {message}")
    return render_template('/contact.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first add action = "/contact" then add csrf_token into your form tag like
<form ction = "/contact" method="POST" class="formone" >
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
</form>
then in python code change route name like

@app.route("/contact", methods=["GET", "POST"])
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply, but how does this help me get the user to the second page? I tried this code and didn't seem to change anything. Sorry for bothering you